# MatLab - Return value of the zero() function

Tags: matlab, zero, transfer-function

I'm trying to implement a very simple transfer function to see its zeroes and poles. For example:

```
s=tf('s');
H= (s+5)/(s^2+3*s+2);
zeroes_H=zero(H);
poles_H=pole(H);
```

I can't seem to get the return values from the `zero()` and from the `pole()` functions. When I check my previous notes my code seems to work fine. What is a possible reason for the problem? Could it be related to a version difference? ( I was using 2019. Now I switched back to 2014.) If it is, what would be a more suitable way for the implementation?

Comment: Does the code run and not return values or are there warnings/errors?

Comment: @David I get an error message for the line with zero() function, related to 'subsindex', stating: "Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'tf'." From what I understand I am passing the argument H in an incorrect way (possibly?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the input of [`zero`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/zero.html) must be a *system* (in fact, a SISO, single-input-single-output system). So go with

```
% create transfer function
sys = tf([1,5],[1,3,2]);

zeroes_H = zero(sys);
poles_H = pole(sys);
```

Comment: Great! This method seems to work just fine without any problems. Just one detail: My initial code just started working properly today without any changes whatsoever. However I believe the solution you've shared is the better way.